# If a very distant supernova has a high Doppler effect redshift do our eyes see its evolution picture like in 'slow motion'?

Tags: astronomy, space-expansion, doppler-effect, supernova

If a very distant supernova has a high Doppler effect redshift do our eyes see its evolution picture like in 'slow motion'? If a same type of supernova apparently lasts longer if it has more wavelength redshift compared to another one how does the '(distance from Earth)-(time dilation)' diagram look like?

Comment: So a time travel thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wavelengths of the light from the supernova are redshifted by a factor of $1+z$. The duration of the supernova is also increased by the same factor of $1+z$.

The problems with establishing this relationship are that all supernovae (even type Ia) are not identical and their light curve shapes/durations depend on intrinsic wavelength.

However, the available data appear to support this relationship (e.g. [Blondin et al. (2008)](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/589568/meta). A plot from this paper is what you are looking for. It shows a parameter expressing how quickly a type Ia supernova light curve evolves versus $(1+z)^{-1}$.

[image: 1+z time dilation]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A Doppler shift is a rescaling of time in the dependence of all observables on time.

Comment: This lacks any useable information.   A Doppler shift is a change in frequency; the reason  the shift happens depends on the situation.   The putative "slow-motion" view of a supernova may occur if/when the star is moving away from us, but I don't think you've justified that.